# Don't change URL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am having 2  in my HTML lets say X and Y.
X contains a list  of objects and Y shows "different views" filled with relevant data related to the item clicked in X.

Suppose if (Lemon,Orange etc) are clicked I will be showed it properties like "Sourness" "weight"
Suppose if (Wine,Beer) is clicked I will be showed it's properties like "Alcohol%" etc.

Since properties are different so I created different views and passed parameters accordingly to show apt data.

If I am not wrong we will use $routeProvider and then have .config defined , pass some parameters etc. But this "changes my URL" , and I don't want that.

Is it even possible what I am wishing in AngularJS?

P.S Check this [Link](http://www.angularbasics.co.uk/Examples/Example.php?Name=SPA2.html#/List) out and keep an eye on the URL as you select different names :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is in your config file.

You need to look into ng-view, and templates. Conditionally loading is possible in AngularJS via a ? variable in the URL. You can map this thanks to $location.search() finding it for you as a hash.

In essence, if someone loads lemon you want them clicking on lemon to add a conditional to your url website.com/fruit?v=lemon

$location.search() will return {"v":"lemon"}

Using $location.search()["v"] will allow you to retrieve the string "lemon" and than simply remap it via your config to show "sourness/weight" html

```
 function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('?v=lemon', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/lemon.html',
        controller: 'lemonCtrl'
    }).
```

Etc.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you but what I asked for is suppose I have a url "www.myurl.com" then I want even on clicking on Lemon,Beer etc. present in "<div> X" my url remains same i.e. "www.myurl.com" but routing makes it "www.myurl.com/#/lemon" . I searched and all I got is how to remove "#" only.Would be helpful if you can provide some link.
Hope now I am clear. I can edit question if it was unclear :)

Comment: You can grab the location of #lemon with the $location.path variable and than in a controller bind it to scope with $scope.lemon = $location.path(). Finally your html you could inject this into a div using <div ng-controller="MainCtrl"><div id=" {{ lemon }}> etc. 

This would allow you to conditionally select the div you are looking for. Am I understanding the question correctly?

Comment: In your answer if I make empty string i.e. when(''...) instead of when('?v=lemon'...) will  I get the result I want. Also if you visit the link I provided observe the url and now select any one of the name say "Albert Einstein" and see the url change. I don't want that.

Comment: The only method of getting around the URL change that I am aware of is by using this third party library: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router
UI-View lets you totally control the way visitors see your URL.
UI-View can also be nested whereas ng-view cannot be nested. Best of luck

Comment: Thnx :) This will do :)